# Independent/Easy fraction of sentences over PA

Tags: lo.logic, proof-theory, peano-arithmetic, induction

Let $S(n)$ be the set of all sentences over PA of length at most $n$ (counting the quantifier symbols, boolean connectives, arithmetic operations and constants, and counting each variable as length $1$).

Let $I(n) = \{ φ : φ \in S(n) \land \text{$φ$ is independent of PA} \}$.

Let $E(n) = \{ φ : φ \in S(n) \land \text{PA$^-$ proves or disproves $φ$} \}$.   [PA$^-$ is defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Equivalent_axiomatizations).]
$
\def\lfrac#1#2{{\large\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$

> I think $\lfrac{\#(I(n))}{\#(S(n))} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, contrary to the conjecture at the end of [this paper](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~cristian/aam.pdf).

My intuition is that it is relatively easy for a random sentence to be provable or disprovable just because of some provable example or counter-example. But I am not sure how to go about proving this. Is there any simple trick I am missing?

> Also, I suspect $\lfrac{\#(I(n))+\#(E(n))}{\#(S(n))} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$, but I am unsure.

This is actually an attempt to capture the idea that most statements that are not decided by PA$^-$ cannot be decided by PA. In intuitive terms I am trying to say that most statements are either easy to prove or disprove or independent of PA. Is any such thing true?

I posted this question [on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2107635/21820) about a year ago but did not get any response, so I hope someone here can help. I would be quite surprised if my first conjecture is false! But neither conjecture seem to yield to structural induction or padding tricks.

Comment: I think something along the lines "almost every valid sentence in PA contains a subsequence $\land 0=1\land$" should work. Two problems I see are that 1. I don't know if strings containing a given substring are "dense" among _valid_ strings, but I don't think this should be too difficult, 2. the $\land 0=1\land$ might appear in some subexpression, hence not invalidating the statement.

Comment: To cast some doubt on the second conjecture, it is easy to generate sentences independent of PA-, eg:  $\forall x \exists y\ y^2 \le x < (y+1)^2$

Comment: @Wojowu: That's exactly the problem. Such constant strings will appear with increasing probability as $n \to \infty$, but they may appear under a quantifier. But that's the kind of reason I think my conjectures are true.

Comment: @MattF.: That in my opinion does not cast sufficient doubt on the second conjecture, because we take $n \to \infty$. We can easily generate such sentences, but for longer sentences it gets harder to pick a random one that is like yours. In any case, if you can disprove my second conjecture then please post a proof outline! =)

Comment: @MattF.: And by the way the paper that I linked to conjectures that $\#(I(n))/\#(S(n)) \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$, which if true would in fact imply that my second conjecture is true! But my first conjecture is completely opposite to theirs...

Comment: @user21820 : I think that Wojowu's suggestion can be adjusted as follows. Define an "atomic" sentence to be a sentence that is not the conjunction of two shorter sentences. Sentences are therefore conjunctions of atomic sentences. Then maybe almost every sentence contains 0=1 as an atomic conjunct?

Comment: @TimothyChow: I don't think it works as you stated, but it gave me an idea. Perhaps we can prove an expected bound on the length of atomic sentences, and then the original sentence is some boolean combination of atomic sentences. If there is nonzero probability of an atomic sentence being decidable by PA−, then we might be able to get nonzero probability of the whole being decided too. Let me think about it later; got to go!

Comment: I’d want clarifications before trusting conclusions from that paper. 1) What is the definition of a finitely specified theory, and does PA qualify? 2) Why do they give a sophisticated proof that the fraction of true sentences of length n is positive?  Obviously at least 1/15^n are true by looking at the truth of not(SS...Sn=0).  If the bound is uniform, what is it numerically? 3) Why doesn’t theorem 5.2 prove their conjecture at the end?  If the fraction of provable sentences among true sentences goes to 0, then the fraction of provable sentences among all sentences must go to 0 too.

Comment: @MattF.: (1) I presume "finitely-specified" means "has a proof verifier program", so PA qualifies. (2) Clearly they mean bounded above some strictly positive **constant** regardless of $n$, but it's possible that the specific encoding could affect that constant and it might be possible to prove a limit without explicit bound. (3) I didn't check their paper, and I see you are right that their theorem 5.2 (if true) implies their conjecture at the end and also implies that my first conjecture is false. Hmm...

Answer (score 2):

The question of limiting fractions is obviously sensitive to the presentation and ordering of sentences.  Meanwhile we can get some results for sentences of the form $$Q\vec{x}\ p(\vec{x})=0$$ where $Q\vec{x}$ is a sequence of quantifiers over variables in $\mathbf{N}$, and $p$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbf{Z}$, in which every variable in $\vec{x}$ appears non-trivially.  We can regard these as abbreviations of sentences of the form $Q\vec{x}\ p(\vec{x})=q(\vec{x})$, where $p$ and $q$ have coefficients in $\mathbf{N}$.

Since every sentence of first-order arithmetic is equivalent under $PA^-$ to such a sentence, this is a reasonable set of sentences to consider.  We can order the sentences to put the low-coefficient, low-degree, low-variable polynomials first.  We find the following.

- When $Q$ is $\emptyset$:  $PA^-$ settles all sentences of the form $p(1)=0$.
- When $Q$ is $\forall x$:  $PA^-$ settles all sentences of the form $\forall x \ p(x)=0$, and proves them false.
- When $Q$ is $\exists x$:  $PA^-$ settles all sentences of the form $\exists x \ p(x)=0$.  Given $p$, we can find a bound on the roots, prove in $PA^-$ that $p$ is positive for $x$ above that bound, and test in $PA^-$ whether any there are any roots with $x$ below that bound.
- When $Q$ is $\forall x \forall y$:  $PA^-$ settles all sentences of the form $\forall x\forall y \ p(x,y)=0$, and proves them false.
- When $Q$ is $\exists x \forall y$:  $PA^-$ settles all sentences of the form $\exists x\forall y \ p(x,y)=0$, mostly proving them false.  Either we can instantiate an $x$, and $PA^-$ proves the claim $\forall y$; or we can choose a number of $y$'s depending on the degree of $p$ and $PA^-$ proves that $p(x,0),\ p(x,1),\ldots p(x,d)$ have no common root.

After this things get more interesting:

- When $Q$ is $\forall x \exists y$: $PA^-$ *cannot* settle all of these, but $PA$ can.  For instance, $PA$ proves $\forall x \exists y\ (x-2y)(x-2y-1)=0$.  However, this is false in the model of $PA^-$ whose domain is the eventually non-negative polynomials in $\mathbf{Z}[t]$, so it is independent of $PA^-$.
- When $Q$ is $\exists x \exists y$: $PA^-$ *cannot* settle all of these, and it's open whether $PA$ can.  For instance, $PA$ disproves $\exists x \exists y\ (x+1)^2-2y^2=0$.  However, this is true in the model of $PA^-$ whose domain is the eventually non-negative polynomials in $\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{2}][t]$ with integer constant terms, so it is independent of $PA^-$.  An effective version of Falting's theorem would presumably show that $PA$ settles all of these sentences.

It seems to me that as the degrees and quantifiers increase, a positive fraction of these sentences will be settled by $PA$ but not by $PA^-$, which is contrary to the second conjecture.  In any case, this seems to be one interesting way to focus the question.

Comment: I don't buy your claim in your last paragraph, because your first bullet point under "things get more interesting" is misleading in my opinion, if not false. It is a fact that PA cannot prove some $Π_2$-sentence, since PA cannot prove totality of some total program. It seems to me likely that with increasing sentence length the probability of a random $Π_2$-sentence being independent of PA goes to $1$, and so that bullet point would not be relevant to the second conjecture. However, if you can in fact prove your conjecture, it would be very interesting!

Comment: I stand by the claim that PA settles all sentences of the form $\forall x \exists y\ p(x,y)=0$.  This would fail if p were complicated; but for polynomial p in two variables, this is either easy to falsify or easy to prove by a recurrence on the y’s, as in the example I gave.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't realize you were not talking about arbitrary $Π_2$-sentences. Still, the results from the paper I linked (that as sentence length increases probability of a true sentence being unprovable goes to $1$) suggest that your claim in your last paragraph is not intuitively true. =)